# java - How to print link text available on the URL?

Tags: java, url, hyperlink

Currently, I am able to print all the URLs of a page but not able to print the text available on the URL....

For example:

```
<a class="fbl" href="/preferences?hl=en" jsaction="foot.cst" id="fsettl">Settings</a>
```

The code is able to print only "/preferences?hl=en", but not the text of the link i.e., Settings....

```
public static List getLinks(String uriStr) {

List result = new ArrayList<String>();
//create a reader on the html content
try{
    System.out.println("in the getlinks try");
URL url = new URI(uriStr).toURL();
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

// Parse the HTML
EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
kit.read(rd, doc, 0);

// Find all the A elements in the HTML document
HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);
while (it.isValid()) {
    SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet)it.getAttributes();

    String link = (String)s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
    if (link != null) {
            // Add the link to the result list
            System.out.println(link);
        //System.out.println("link print finished");
        result.add(link);
    }
    //System.out.println(link);
    it.next();
}
}
```

How would I print the content of the URL?

Comment: you wan't to parse a google search page?

Comment: The one who advised against use of other frameworks should have advised against stackoverflow as well.  Most tools you mentioned are open source. Why not check the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class PrintURL {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
Reader r = null;

     try {
        URL u = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/");
        // URL u = new URL(args[0]);
        InputStream in = u.openStream();
        r = new InputStreamReader(in);

        Document jsoup = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.co.in/").get();
        Elements aHref = jsoup.getElementsByTag("a");
        Iterator<Element> iterator = aHref.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Element element = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("\nLink: " + element.attr("href")); 
            System.out.println("Link Name: " + element.text());
        }
                 } finally {
        if (r != null) {
            r.close();
          }
         }
        }
      }
```